# Check MS Office license status via Office Automation or with other way

Tags: c#, c++, vba, office-automation

Is there a way to check Word, Excel and/or Powerpoint license status via office automation interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the object models provide no functionality to check on licenses or anything similar.

Edit: For follow-up see:
[Check MS Office license status programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436518/check-ms-office-license-status-programmatically)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know whether there are other ways to check license status for 2007-2016 office?

Comment: @JohnBosco. No, I don't. If there's information available it would be in the Registry, although I can't recall having ever encountered that when "snooping around". But it may just be because I never looked for it... A good place to ask might be in the IT Pro (TechNet) forums on MSDN. That's where network and admin issues are handled, including things like group policies and Registry settings. Someone there might know.